# Get content from div before break

Tags: ruby, hpricot

Using hpricot I can get the content of some divs  -

```
doc = Hpricot(@response)

doc.search(".someDiv").each do |content|
   puts content.inner_html
end
```

//this puts the following

```
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<br>
some more text, images and other stuff
```

How can I make sure I only put the stuff before the line break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the paragraph structure is the same for all divs you could always **split** the *content*:

```
doc = Hpricot(@response)

doc.search(".someDiv").each do |content|
   puts content.inner_html.split("<br>").first
end
```